# How to extend rational parametrization of the circle to three dimensions?

Tags: geometry, 3d

I recently became aware of the **rational parametrization of the circle** in two dimensions:

$$\left(\frac{1-m^2}{1+m^2}, \frac{2m}{1+m^2}\right)$$

for a unit circle centered on the origin.

I'm interested in **extending this to an arbitrary circle in three dimensions**, in particular given the center, normal and radius.

I'd like the result to still be a *rational* parametrization.

Comment: Note: still looking for a **circle**, $S^1$ not sphere $S^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick two unit vectors $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ so that together with the specified normal they form an orthonormal frame. The parametrization you want is $$\mathbf c + \frac{1-m^2}{1+m^2}r\mathbf u+\frac{2m}{1+m^2}r\mathbf v,$$
where $\mathbf c$ and $r$ are the center and radius of the circle. What we're doing is simply taking the $xy$ plane that the original circle lies in, and mapping the origin to $\mathbf c$ and the $x$ and $y$ axes to $r\mathbf u$ and $r\mathbf v$.